# How to set a common dynamic value for all Django models in Django admin page?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-forms, django-admin

I have an application, where i have created a next button to redirect to the next model. What i want is that, when i am in the first admin page, eg. Master is the model, and it is connected with other models based foreign key relationship. I want this Master ID, to get automatically populate when the next button is click.

I thought of using cookies but i am not able to understand how to make change in the forms.py. I have created an API for setting and getting the API.

**views.py**

```
def setcookie(request):
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/core/masterfertilizer/add/')
    response.set_cookie('crop', request.GET.get("crop_id"))
    return response


def getcookie(request):
    crop_id = request.COOKIES['crop']
    return JsonResponse({'data': [crop_id]})
```

**admin.py**

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
   if "_next" in request.POST:
       return redirect(f'/core/setcookie/crop_id?crop_id={obj}')
   return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

**crop.js**

```
function getCropID(){
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/core/getcookie/', function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
        document.querySelector('#id_master_crop_id').value=parseInt(x.split(';')[1].split('=')[1]);
        });
}
```

**forms.py**

```
self.fields['master_crop_id'].widget = forms.Select(
     attrs={
     'id': 'id_master_crop_id',
     'onchange': 'getCropID()',
     'style': 'width:200px'
     },
)
```

Comment: do you want that `attrs['id']` field to be automatically set to some unique value ?

Answer (score 1):

hello maybe what you need here is to take a look at paginator and you can decide to view one element peer page so your next button can show you the next object and so one no need of cookie for that.

Comment: ok, i'll have a look at paginator.